# how to create an extent which is not parallel to X and Y axis R raster

Tags: r, raster

I have below code which creates an extent that is parallel to X and Y axis.

Is there a way to create an extent which is not straight - for example I would like to create 2 lines that are parallel to to one diagonal. But one line is below that diagonal by 10 pixels and the other line is above the diagonal by 10 pixels. Create 2 more lines in similar manner but around the other diagonal and use those 4 lines as edges of my extent

```
library(raster)
r1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x <- crop(r1, extent(0,50,0,50))
plotRGB(x)

png("aaa.png",width=20,height=20)
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
image(crop(x,extent(c(0,30,0,30))))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

An extent is by definition rectangular (at least in the raster package). But you can define a polygon and use that to crop & mask your raster data.

```
library(raster)
r <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
plotRGB(r)
p <- spPolygons(rbind(c(20, 20), c(30, 50), c(70, 50), c(60, 20)))
plot(p, add=TRUE, lwd=4, border='red')

x <- crop(r, p)
m <- mask(x, p)
plotRGB(m)
plot(p, add=TRUE, lwd=4, border='red')
```

Comment: This is producing output as expected. But i also want to save that output at original scale and without any background. Please add that part

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying `select()` with `use="pol"` parameter. This will allow for an interactive selection of a region on a plot, although the resulting region might not be as precise as you want it.

Edit with a code:

Here is how I would go about it:
`x1 <- select(x, use = "pol")`

This will open x as an image in a new window (in Plots tab if you use RStudio). Now you can use your mouse to select a region: just click on points which surround the region you want to have. After you are done clicking hit Esc and the new image will be saved as `x1` object. You can print/save it then.

Comment: i would appreciate if you can provide some sample code